# How to Block chrome://extensions/ URL?

Tags: google-chrome, url, blocking

How can you block the Chrome URL: `chrome://extensions/`, such that extensions cannot be disabled, removed, or disabled in incognito mode by anyone (or without a password)?

**What I've Tried (that's failed):**

- blacklisting the URL using my xfinity routers parental controls or OpenDNS doesn't work, since it doesn't recognize that format of URL (it expects `http://...` and using `chrome` didn't work either).
- I have Windows 7 Home, which prevents me from using Group Policy Editor (gpedit.msc) to blacklist chrome URLs such as `chrome://*` through the administrative template google provides for Chrome.
- Kiosk mode in chrome accomplishes this but it also limits the user too much (removing the address bar and shortcuts). Also, it can easily be evaded by typing <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F4</kbd>. I would like password protection from access to Chromes internal URLs such as extensions.
- Denying write access to all user's Chrome Extensions directory. This only prevents *new* extensions from being installed. It doesn't prevent *current* extensions from being disabled.
- Creating supervised user accounts. Although they prevent extensions from being modified they also do not allow *any* extensions to be installed in the first place!

Comment: Are you perhaps looking for the so-called kiosk mode?

Comment: @DanielB - thanks, but that limits the user too much. I'd like all the functionality of Chrome but without access to internal chrome URLs such as extensions. I updated my question to reflect this

Answer (score 2):

Working as of March 11, 2023 on Version 111.0.5563.65

Use Chrome's URLBlocklist policy

On Windows, the Registry key to block sites can be found under `Software\Policies\Google\Chrome\URLBlocklist` in the `HKCU` or `HLM` hive. Refer to the link at the bottom for other systems.

Unlike solutions using the Group Policy Editor, this will work under all versions of Windows (Home, Pro, etc) with admin rights.

1. Navigate to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Google\Chrome\URLBlocklist` using the [Registry Editor](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/how-to-open-registry-editor-in-windows-10-deab38e6-91d6-e0aa-4b7c-8878d9e07b11). Create these keys if necessary by right clicking each "folder" and selecting New > Key
2. Create a REG_SZ string value with an integer as the title and a value of `chrome://extensions` by right-clicking and selecting "string value"
3. To force a refresh, navigate to chrome://policy and click the "Reload policies" button at the top of the page.

The documentation for this feature has the following note:

> Note: Blocking internal chrome://* and chrome-untrusted://* URLs can
> lead to unexpected errors or can be circumvented in some cases.

For more information and for other devices, see [Google's documentation](https://chromeenterprise.google/policies/?policy=URLBlocklist) for this policy.

Here's also a screenshot of my registry editor (I've blocked out irrelevant keys)
[image: Screenshot of registry editor]

Answer (score 1):

You can try with providing the Permission to the Goggle Chrome Extensions ( Allow/ Deny ) for the particular User's.

GOTO this location

**%LOCALAPPDATA%\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Extensions**

To disable write access, Right Click the Extensions -> properties -> security -> edit -> Select the User.

Hit **Allow/Deny** on check box and they will/ will not be able to install extensions.

[image]

**Hope this helps.**

Comment: @vernbutech - thanks, this is a useful trick for preventing further extensions from being installed. However, my goal is to prevent *current* extensions from being **disabled**, or **removed**. I updated my answer clarifying this.

Comment: @vembutech Something tells me you haven't tested this before. I'm saying this because I've done a good amount of testing with this method, e.g. disabling 'Write' for SYSTEM, Admins & the user. It does NOT work. One can still install extensions.

Answer (score 0):

Try extension StayFocused, or Cold Turkey Blocker. The former is capable of doing that by default.

[Here is a screenshot of StayFocused's function.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TfNOK.png)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).