# Lock extensions in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions

I am in a constant battle with myself over the issue of procrastination.  In general:

1. I find a distraction
2. I block myself from accessing it
3. One day I want to see it so I figure out a way around the block
4. Eventually the way of circumventing the block becomes automatic, muscle-memory
5. Now the distraction is back and I need to find a new way to keep myself away from it

Right now I am blocking a ton of sites using the BlockSite extension.  It's great, makes me go entirely cold turkey.  But the problem is, it's easy to disable by just going to Window > Extensions and flicking it off.  Now that's becoming automatic for me and the issue is back, so the extension is basically useless.

Is there a way, in Chrome, to disable access to the extensions page, remove it from the Window menu, lock it with a password, or otherwise make it difficult to access?  I would imagine there must be since there are a number of parental supervision extensions and if this wasn't possible, kids could easily disable those in much the same way.

Comment: Related: [How to Block chrome://extensions/ URL?](https://superuser.com/q/857892/152004)

Answer (score 1):

You could try to disable the extensions page, chrome://extensions/

If the extension itself or chrome allows you to do that...

I use StayFocusd. Another awesome site blocker.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are looking for something like "Managed Users" in Chrome. Have another Google Account that can control what you can access.

https://www.chrome.com/manage

Otherwise, you could always block it from outside your computer. I don't usually have any issues with websites, but sometimes with games, so I have a separate OS install for just games. It makes in inconvenient to reboot and play games while I am working on something. I just have to know the rule to not install games on the other install. For websites, you could block yourself at the router level or setup your own firewall.

To make it really bad for yourself have someone else setup the password for whatever you choose and make them log in whenever you want to take it down temporarily.