# How to hide the Google Chrome extensions page

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions, blocking

I use Blocksite when I am studying in Google Chrome. I see my social networks very often and I can't study or work without this blocker. However, sometimes I get lost and go to the Google Chrome extensions page: "chrome://extensions/", and easily disable this page blocker.

I would like to know if there is a way to hide this path "chrome://extensions/" or if a password can be created to access this path.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Lock extensions in Chrome](https://superuser.com/questions/900557/lock-extensions-in-chrome)

Answer (score 0):

Try StayFocused or WasteNoTime extensions. They can block extension page. Here is an example from StayFocused:

[image]