# How to get rid of the "This can read or change site data" option for Chrome extensions

Tags: google-chrome

Trying to block this option so I can't bypass the Cold Turkey blocker.

If there is a way to do this using the registry editor then that would be great. I already did this for incognito mode however I can't find any guides on how to do this for this option.

Cold Turkey works fine when blocking applications so I can change the settings to all sites disable the option using the registry editor then just block the registry editor.

If there are any other ways I'm open to them as well.

Comment: Please explain a bit more. You got a piece of software to help you with selfcontrol and now you are asking how to make it harder to evade it? How are you evading it currently? "This can read or change site data" is a warning right, not an option?

Comment: There are [8 questions](https://superuser.com/search?q=%22Cold+Turkey%22+is%3Aquestion) besides this one with "Cold Turkey". Please review them tell us if there is one that is related to what you are trying to do and in such case why it don't meet your needs.

Comment: @Gantendo "You got a piece of software to help you with selfcontrol and now you are asking how to make it harder to evade it?" yes "How are you evading it currently?" On just basic chrome when you click extensions then click on the three dots next to an extension there is an option which says 'This can read and change site data' when you click on that you can then select the option 'when you click this extension' I want to know if there is a way to remove that option. I followed another guide which helped me remove incognito using the registry editor it appears greyed out when done right.

Comment: Interesting question. It is certainly possible via GPO (google: gpo block chrome settings). I wrote a feature request for the developer. Note also that https://superuser.com/questions/857892/how-to-block-chrome-extensions-url#:~:text=%25LOCALAPPDATA%25%5CGoogle%5CChrome%5C,be%20able%20to%20install%20extensions exists. You may be able to block it using StayFocused.

Answer (score 0):

The programmer of Cold Turkey writes:

> "My app as well, just block chrome://extensions:
> https://getcoldturkey.com/support/how-to/block-chrome-urls/
> ​
>
> You shouldn't even need to do this though (since there are other ways to remove extensions). My app will block your browser (when disabling/removing the extension) during locked blocks. To lock your block, just click the link under the toggle switch where you started the block. By default, it'll say "unlocked." Once you click that a popup will open where you can choose how to lock the block."

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem.
I'll proceed explaining how I could solve it.

1. <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>
2. write "regedit".
3. In the registry editor, go to: `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Google\Chrome`.
4. Create a new folder called `ExtensionInstallForcelist`.
5. Create a new string value (name it whatever you want).
6. In the value information, paste the package name of the chrome extension (you'll find it in the Chrome store or in the extension's menu).
7. Save it.
8. Restart Chrome. You will have no longer access to that sub menu, you won't be able to get rid of this UNLESS you delete the string in your registry (still figuring out how to block access to that specific part of the registry).

---

**Edit**: I found the way! Be sure to do this AFTER you've created all the strings and you see that there are no further errors in your browser.

1. Right-click on the new key you've created.
2. Click on permissions.
3. Click on advanced options.
4. Click on remove inheritance.
5. Double click on SYSTEM and your administrator user. Untick total control and only tick "read".

Now you're finally free from this binge!